# Computer Vision ocr API returning http response: Unsupported Media Type for Java http request

Tags: java, apache, http, spring-boot, azure-cognitive-services

I'm making an OCR post request to the MS ccomputer visions APi and it returns the reponse: HTTP/1.1 415 Unsupported Media Type [Cache-Control: no-cache, Pragma: no-cache, Content-Length: 183, Content-Type: application/json; etc, etc.

here's my Java code, adding a multipartfile(jpg) to the request and then posting it.

```
HttpClient httpClient = HttpClientBuilder.create().build();

    String fileContentType = file.getContentType();
    URI uri = buildUri();

    if(uri == null){
        //throw some exception
    }

    HttpPost request = new HttpPost(uri);

    request.setHeader("Content-Type", fileContentType);
    request.setHeader("Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key", subscriptionKey);

    MultipartEntityBuilder mpEB = MultipartEntityBuilder.create();


    InputStream fileInputStream = file.getInputStream();

    //modify method to add filename if later need arises
    //link: https://memorynotfound.com/apache-httpclient-multipart-upload-request/
    mpEB.addBinaryBody("image", fileInputStream);
    mpEB.setContentType(ContentType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA);

    HttpEntity image = mpEB.build();
    request.setEntity(image);

    HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(request);
    HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();

    System.out.println(json.toString());
    //dataFromJsonExtractor.extractData(json);

}
private URI buildUri(){

    URI link = null;
    try {
        URIBuilder builder = new URIBuilder(uriBase);

        builder.setParameter("language", "de");

        URI uri = builder.build();

        link = uri;
        }catch (URISyntaxException e){
        logger.debug("Computer Vision API URL Builder creation error: " + e);

    }

    return link;
}
```

Any help? Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It'll be a lot simpler if you just post the single image payload in to the POST body, rather than constructing a multipart MIME body, since you can only post one image at a time anyway.  Code could look like this:

```
public static void run(FileDataSource file) throws Exception
{
    HttpClient httpClient = HttpClientBuilder.create().build();

    URI uri = buildUri();

    HttpPost request = new HttpPost(uri);

    request.setHeader("Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key", subscriptionKey);

    HttpEntity entity = EntityBuilder
        .create()
        .setStream(file.getInputStream())
        .setContentType(ContentType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM)
        .build();

    request.setEntity(entity);

    HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(request);
    HttpEntity jsonEntity = response.getEntity();

    System.out.println(EntityUtils.toString(jsonEntity));
}
```

Note that the API expects `application/octet-stream` as the content type, not `image/*`.

Comment: Cheers!! Worked like a charm for your ContentType of Octet Stream. Didn't work for multipart Form though even though it's in the docs. Weird. Thanks.